# How can I resize an animated gif in JavaScript or HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, animated-gif

I need to show an animation On SplashScreen for Android. I want to resize it for screen's height-width.  I can succeed it fit to screen with using webView and javascript. But I cant resize it:)

I write my code, maybe somebody will need it..

This is html code in index.html ( I could write it on Java, but I cant show animated-gif that using )

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
<script type="text/javascript">

function resize(image)
{
    var differenceHeight = document.body.clientHeight - image.clientHeight;
    var differenceWidth  = document.body.clientWidth  - image.clientWidth;
    if (differenceHeight < 0) differenceHeight = differenceHeight * -1;
    if (differenceWidth  < 0) differenceWidth  = differenceWidth * -1;

    if (differenceHeight > differenceWidth)
    {
        image.style['height'] = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
    }
    else
    {
        image.style['width'] = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
    }

    // Optional: remove margins or compensate for offset.
    image.style['margin'] = 0;
    document.body.style['margin'] = 0;
}

</script>
<img src="file:///android_asset/html/screen1.gif"
     onload="resize(this);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my WebView:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

Comment: I'm confused about what isn't working. This seems like it should be doing what you want...

Comment: width is OK, but animation's height is longer than screen's

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the ratio of the height and width of the image to the ratio of the height and width of the display.

```
var imageRatio = image.clientHeight / image.clientWidth;
var clientRatio = document.body.clientHeight / document.body.clientWidth;

if (imageRatio > clientRatio)
{
    image.style['height'] = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
}
else
{
    image.style['width'] = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
}
```

Comment: I think; you compared ratios but, you didnt resize image for this ratios. I need resize image to screen's ratio?

Comment: I tried it here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qvsb9/) Is this the functionality that you want? (You can resize the result box to simulate different widths and heights of the device)

Comment: my device screen is 480x800 pixels. But I cant see this pixels on webview? webView is fullscreen. Alsa why we can not set height and width, when I set two values, image is bigger than screen... I remind you that my image is animated-gif